# How to edit many comments of a demans in controller

Tags: symfony

I display a demands and all of of his comments

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$valider = $em->find('PublishDemandsBundle:Demands', $id);
$comments = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Pcomment')->findByDemands($valider);
```

I need to edit  custoom seen in table comments of all comments :$comments  how can i make this to edit all comments of a demand:

```
$comments ->setSeen(true);
$em->persist($comments);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  $comment->setSeen(true);
}
$em->flush();
```